# How to get the email Id of facebook Group Members

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-group

Suppose I am a member of group **A** which has around 700 members. Is there any way to get the email ids of those 700 members? If yes than how come we make it possible and what is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't get email id's of the users you are a member of and this is because Facebook respects the privacy options of the individuals. If you still need the email id of the members then you may ask them to authorize the Facebook application which with 'email' permissions can access the email ID.